# how do i use tkiner to get the text in binary from entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption

i have the problem that i cant use the entry.get command if i have it in my code then nothing happens, i even tried just printing the key_entry.get() instantly
like here

```
key = key_entry.get()
print(key)
```

but still nothing was seen

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import pyperclip
import os

    



root = Tk()

key_entry = tk.Entry(root,bg="grey", fg="green",width="50")
key_entry.place(x=35, y=100)

def select_key():
    with open("file.key", "rb") as file:
        file.read(key)

def generate_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    key_entry.delete(0,"end")
    key_entry.insert(0,key)


def save_key_to_file():
    key = key_entry.get()
    print(key)
    key = key_entry.get().encode('utf-8')
    with open("file.key", "wb") as file:
        file.write(key)


load_button = tk.Button(root, text="Load Key", state="normal", borderwidth=0, bg="black", fg="green", activebackground='#2e2e2e', activeforeground="green")
load_button.place(x=359, y=130)

save_button = tk.Button(root, command=save_key_to_file(),text="Save Key", state="normal", borderwidth=0, bg="black", fg="green", activebackground='#2e2e2e', activeforeground="green")
save_button.place(x=270, y=130)

def button_clicked():
    generate_key()

button = tk.Button(text="Generate key", borderwidth=0, bg="black", fg="green", activebackground='#2e2e2e', activeforeground="green", command=button_clicked)
button.place(x=35, y=130)


root.mainloop()
```

it should save the file as file.key but it doesnt if i click the button it doesnt do a thing

Comment: `command=save_key_to_file()` calls the function *right now*  - as the GUI is being created, before the user could have possibly typed in anything.  You need `command=save_key_to_file` instead, to specify a function to be called later.

Comment: `command=` needs `callback` - it means function's name without `()` and without arguments

Comment: What does file.key look like?

Comment: @toyotaSupra it is a key for encryption and it has the key in it after i finish my project you can view it at my github the name is as same as the one on stack overflow and i will be posting also the the open source

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki as i said it is'nt a ransomware it self, actually it functions like one but without encrypting the whole pc.and it's a project so u can encrypt files or folders. idk why everyone is thinking its a ransomware?? can't i just make a software with encryption and if it would be a ransomeware i wouldn't post it in stackoverflow there are tons of youtube videos out there for it. so what's your point your trying to make??

Comment: @toyotaSupra i finished the project here https://github.com/P1xelcyber/Encrypto-

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is causing is because you are using `()` at the end of the function which is passed as a parameter.The `command=` parameter requires a callback(or you could use lambda functions).

When you do `command=save_key_to_file()`,the function is ran at the starting of the program.

- Insted to make it work when you click it,you need to add it as a `callback`

```py
save_button = tk.Button(root, command=save_key_to_file,text="Save Key", state="normal", borderwidth=0, bg="black", fg="green", activebackground='#2e2e2e', activeforeground="green")
```

- Or else if you need to pass some arguments to `save_key_to_file(args)` then you can use `lambda` functions.

```py
save_button = tk.Button(root,command=lambda:save_key_to_file('custom_file_name'),text="Save Key", state="normal", borderwidth=0, bg="black", fg="green", activebackground='#2e2e2e', activeforeground="green")
```

hope this helps.